# how to get an HTML from a .txt file and interpret it in an [InnerHtml] Angular 8

Tags: html, angular, frontend, innerhtml, angular-directive

From an admin module of my app I save a html in a .txt file which is stored in an Azure blobstorage, in the front (an Angular 8 application) I get the URL of that file and get its content to display a view ,

so in the **admin module** I wrote something like this:

```
<div>
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Parrafo</p>
<div>
```

then in **the front** I get something like this:

```
<div><br></div><div><br></div><div><br></div>&lt;div&gt;<div>&lt;h1&gt;Title&lt;/h1&gt;</div><div>&lt;p&gt;Paragraph&lt;/p&gt;</div><div>&lt;div&gt;</div>
```

with a lot of additional "div's" and sometimes with span tags

when **I use the [innerHtml] directive to interpret it in a div like this:**

```
<div [innerHTML]="HtmlFromFile">
</div>
```

**I get nothing displayed in the view, but in the inspect element window it shows the following:**

```
<div><br></div><div><br></div><div><br></div>&lt;div&gt;<div>&lt;h1&gt;Title&lt;/h1&gt;</div><div>&lt;p&gt;Paragraph&lt;/p&gt;</div><div>&lt;div&gt;</div>
```

when **I put it in a H1 tag** (just to test) like this:

```
<h1 [innerHTML]="HtmlFromFile">
</h1>
```

it **displays in the view** the following:

```
<h1> Title </h1>
<p>Parrafo</p>
```

**instead of a**

> **Title** Parrafo

as I wish

what is happening?

Comment: Does the Admin Module build up the html using a rich text editor? That might explain the additional elements.

Comment: yes it does it uses a rich text editor, could that be the problem ?

Comment: Rich text editors will often use additional elements to achieve formatting (bold, italic, underline, spacing, etc...). They will also escape any special characters, which is most likely why you're seeing `&lt;div&gt;`

Comment: Also note that Angular most likely views the HTML content as a security risk. You may need to sanitize the text use [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) before you can render it.

`const trustedHtml = DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(HtmlFromFile)`